# Adding additional AWS resources to CdkPipeline application stages

Tags: typescript, pipeline, aws-cdk

Let's say I have a `ParentStack` and it includes a cross-account `CdkPipeline`. There are several deployment environments (AWS accounts) and for each one there's an `AppStage` which instantiates an actual `AppService` with its resources.

The idea is to create a generalized pipeline and then add arbitrary resources to it on a per-app basis.

For example, I thought it will be possible to do something like this:

```
const app = new cdk.App();

const parentStack = new ParentStack(app, "ParentStack");

parentStack.appStages.forEach(stage => {
   new sns.Topic(stage.appService, "MyTopic", { topicName: "my-new-topic" });
});
```

Even though synthesis completes successfully, no additional resources are created on the underlying `service` stack.

Is there a way to achieve the result described above?

Thank you.